# How to set/copy Struct property while decoding JSON content

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have one struct to decode the json content:

```
struct CustomResponse: Decodable {
var network: String
var weight: Int = 0
var pureWeight: Int

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case network = "network"
    case weight = "weight"
}}
```

I'd like to set the initial `weight` value which is parsed from JSON to `pureWeight` property. Even if `weight` is changed later, `pureWeight` should be the one coming from JSON response.

Is there any easy way to set `pureWeight` one time (after parsing) without using manually decode all the json content?

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
...parsing all items one by one.
}
```

I used this code but obviously it always returned the mutated values of weight:

```
 var pureWeight: Int {
    get {
        return weight
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach like following

### Keeping the `init`:

```
import Foundation

let json = """
{
    "network" : "My Awesome network",
    "weight" : 100
}
"""

struct CustomResponse: Decodable {
    var network: String
    var pureWeight: Int

    // Computed
    var weight: Int {
        get {
            return hiddenWeight ?? pureWeight
        }
        set {
            hiddenWeight = newValue
        }
    }

    // Hidden from the outside world
    private var hiddenWeight: Int?


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case network
        case weight
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        network = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .network)
        pureWeight = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .weight)
    }
}

let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
if let data = json.data(using: .utf8),
   var response = try? jsonDecoder.decode(CustomResponse.self, from: data) {

        print(response)
        response.weight = 200
        print(response)
}
```

So what is done here is, maintaining a private property, hidden from the outside world. Initially it's been set to `nil`. While parsed from JSON, it's `nil`.

While getting `weight` property we get hidden property `hiddenWeight` or `weight` in case `hiddenWeight` is nil.

When `weight` is set to something, then `hiddenWeight` is set.

So from next time, whenever `weight` is asked for then `hiddenWeight` is returned.

### Without using `init`:

If you want to omit the `init` implementation, then you have to use any other property name except `weight`. I'm using `myWeight`.

```
import Foundation

let json = """
{
    "network" : "My Awesome network",
    "weight" : 100
}
"""

struct CustomResponse: Decodable {
    var network: String
    var weight: Int

    // Computed
    var myWeight: Int {
        get {
            return hiddenWeight ?? weight
        }
        set {
            hiddenWeight = newValue
        }
    }

    // Hidden from the outside world
    private var hiddenWeight: Int?
}

let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
if let data = json.data(using: .utf8),
   var response = try? jsonDecoder.decode(CustomResponse.self, from: data) {

        print(response)
        response.myWeight = 200
        print(response)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, when I changed it as you suggested, but this time I'm getting "Type 'CustomResponse' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'" error which I coudn't understand yet. I believe it's related set operation.

Comment: @Coldfish check, i've added a working example. May be you we're setting `weight` without setting `pureWeight` in the custom decoder.

Comment: So there's no resolution without using  "init(from decoder: Decoder) throws" as far as I see.

Comment: Yes there is, if you change the naming convention

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You still need a custom `init` but the easiest way to do it then is to `let` declare the initial weight property since it should not change and set it in the `init`

```
struct CustomResponse: Decodable {
    var network: String
    var weight: Int
    let pureWeight: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case network = "network"
        case weight = "weight"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        network = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .network)
        weight = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .weight)
        pureWeight = weight
    }
}
```